# Compiles but getting 'uncaught exception of type std::bad_cast'

Tags: c++, boost

I'm trying to get started with Boost for C++. Here's a small program that compiles with `g++ -Wall test.cpp /usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.55.0/lib/libboost_locale-mt.a`.

However, when I run it, here's the error I get:
`libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type std::bad_cast: std::bad_cast
Abort trap: 6`

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/locale.hpp>

int main(void) {
    char test[] = "Variété";
    boost::locale::to_upper(test);
    std::cout << test << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

What could be the reason here? Thanks!

I'm on Mac OSX Mavericks.

Comment: What if you catch the exception and print its [`what()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/typeinfo/bad_cast/)? Does it give any helpful additional information?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to docs:

> http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/locale/doc/html/group__convert.html#ga7889a57e1bc1059fbb107db0781d0b6d

```
    std::basic_string<CharType> boost::locale::to_lower(CharType const *str,
                                   std::locale const &loc = std::locale())
```

Convert a NUL terminated string str to lower case according to locale loc

Note:
**throws std::bad_cast if loc does not have converter facet installed**

So, this fixes the problem on my machine.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/locale.hpp>

int main(void) {
    std::string test = "Variété";
    std::locale loc = boost::locale::generator().generate("en_US.UTF-8");
    std::string test_u = boost::locale::to_upper(test, loc);
    std::cout << test << " -> " << test_u << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Outputs:

```
Variété -> VARIÉTÉ
```

Comment: Thanks! I had a look at these docs. I can't figure out what I'm missing though. Does the converter not come bundled with the rest of boost?

Comment: I added a working example. Just make a boost locale for conversions.